# How to add VS solution to windows 10 startmenu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, solution, startmenu

Sorry for that not directly programming related question. How can I add my Visual Studio solutions to the Windows 10 start menu as "[secondary tile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh465372.aspx)", so I can easily access them?

Drag&Drop seems to indicate that it is possible (dragging to the start-button prints a "Pin to start menu", but nothing happens), for Edge it works flawlessly (pinning from within the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to add individual solutions to the start menu at this time.